# Unable to start Ubuntu from VMware

Tags: 12.10, vmware

I installed Ubuntu on VMware but when I open Ubuntu all I get is this:

[image]

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Did you install Ubuntu Server, or the desktop version? Is the problem that the GUI doesn't come up? If so, what happens when you try to run `startx`?

Comment: Not trying to be a smart ass or anything, but the message does say to wait for the GUI to launch while Ubuntu is installing. Maybe you just need to wait? How long was it between when you installed versus when you took the above screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've installed Ubuntu using the built-in VMware installer (VMware Easy Install). When creating the VM, try choosing "I will install the operating system later", and before you boot the VM, set the virtual CD to point to your ISO or CD/DVD.

I don't know how the built-in installer works since I've never used it, but I think it lets you enter the details and then it automatically installs the OS. Maybe there are problems with how it works with Ubuntu 12.10.